# Jquery Function required to replace content in a String

Tags: javascript

I have a textarea where users can type content and also include emoticon symbols like :) or ;)

When 'Sent' is pressed the textarea string needs to be parsed to convert any emoticon symbols into `<img>`'s for display.

I can easily generate a list of emoticons and there relevant image like:

```
 ':)' - '<img src="/images/happy.jpg"/>'
 ';)' - '<img src="/images/wink.jpg"/>'
```

I assume the above could be put into an associate array.

Can someone point me in the right direction to create an associate array of emoticon symbol's and html img tags and then parse a string to replace the matching symbols with the html img tags?

Also out of interest is there a better way to do this?

thankyou

Comment: Why would you convert emotion strings to <img src ... and save it that way on your server side? I would save them as they are in the database. However, when rendering the view (webiste for example) I would have a function to convert each smiley to certain IMG...

Comment: Sounds like a job for JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually quite described the behavior:

```
var map = {
    ':)':   '<img src="/images/happy.jpg"/>',
    ';(':   '<img src="/images/wink.jpg"/>'
},
text    = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[ 0 ].value;

Object.keys( map ).forEach(function( ico ) {
    // escape special characters for regex
    var icoE   = ico.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");
    // now replace actual symbols
    text       = text.replace( new RegExp(icoE, 'g'), map[ico] );
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/DBfpw/2/

---

*Edit*
In order to have a valid regular expression created, we need to escape `)` and `(`

*Note*
The above snippet contains *ECMAscript5* featured code. If you need to run that on legacy browsers, make sure to include a *ES5 Shim* library.

*Note 2*
Sorry the above code does **not** contain any jQuery code since its not necessary.

Comment: Note that not all browsers support `keys()` and `forEach()`.

Comment: @bažmegakapa: well, true, but at the current state I'm just going to ignore IE6/7. Call me ignorant.

Comment: String replacement only replace the first occurence. See http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-replace.php. You have to use a regex to handle the case where you have multiple occurences of the same smiley

Comment: @SamuelRossille: right thanks for the headsup. I edited that.

Comment: @jAndy That's fine, I ignore them myself a lot of times. But a lot of people might read this answer and it is surely useful info for them. By the way, [IE8 supports neither](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/), and it is still very widespread and will continue to be.

Comment: May I suggest one improvement: use original smileys as keys, and escape the special chars using answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript so code will be easier to write. I don't edit because i don't want to change the meaning of the answer

Answer (score 2):

I would create an array of objects like:

```
var emoticons = [{regex: /:\)/g, image: "happy"},
                 {regex: /;\)/g, image: "wink"},
                 etc...]
```

And then iterate over that array to make the replacements

```
for(var i = 0; i < emoticons.length; i++) {
    str = str.replace(emoticons[i].regex, 
        '<img src="/' + emoticons[i].image + '.jpg"/>');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use JavaScript to replace emoticons while user is typing. But to send the string with replaced emoticons to the server script is not good way. **It is not safe way** - anyone could replace your content on client side prior submission to the server side script. Saving `<img src="images/sad.jpg">` instead of :-( or some replacement would be better. Less data to store + you can easier replace it with new image/image location and any other string.

So one way would be to post string to the server side script for storing in database. For view rendering (prior sending to browser) you can have function (something like below) that would replace each emoticon string to certain image:

```
<?php
    $text = 'Hey :-), how are you doing bro? Having some fun :-D? Lets meet :-(';

    $smileys = array(
        ':-)' => 'happy',
        ':-(' => 'sad',
        ':-D' => 'tongue'
    );

    foreach($smileys as $key => $value) { 
            $text =  str_replace($key, '<img srce="images/'.$value .'.jpg">', $text);
    }

    echo $text;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Start off by listing all supported emoticons and their names
var emoticons = {
    ":)": "smile",
    ":P": "tongue",
    ":(": "sad",
}, regex = [];

// push a regex for each one (:\)) onto an array.  Escape each special character
// each component is wrapped in unescaped parentheses to *capture* the token
// dynamically building this is optional -
// you may want to generate the regex once and use the literal
for(var emoticon in emoticons) {
    if(emoticons.hasOwnProperty(emoticon)) {
        regex.push("("+emoticon.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1")+")");
    }
}

//join the array to form a string and use the regex OR operator.
regex = new RegExp(regex.join("|"), "g");
// Now the regex looks like this - /(:\))|(:P)|(:\()/g

// String replace function also takes a function as the second parameter.
// The function takes the captured text, (what we put in parenthesis earlier)
// and you can use it to refer to the emoticon hash at the beginning.
// Then you return the desired replaced text.
text = text.replace(regex, function(captured) {
    return "<img src='"+emoticons[captured]+".jpg'/>";
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NCXDK/1) demo of this technique

Comment: That would be a great solution, but just two points miss: 1/ not all emoticon have a length of 2, 2/ I think you must not escape non-special chars. have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript for escaping regexp chars

Comment: Yep, saw your comment on the other post.  Good catch.

Comment: nice answer, but you should check for `Object.hasOwnProperty()` within that `for in` loop. Otherwise, any browser that does not set the *enumerable* descriptor to `false` would loop over any `Object.prototype` property aswell.

Comment: @jAndy Added it.  I guess technically it is The Right Thing, but I am ambivalent about it.